# How to mount persistent volume of specific directory path to default MySQL data dir in Openshift

Tags: mysql, docker, openshift

From the Openshift documentation https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.1/using_images/db_images/mysql.html, it is stated that default data directory of MySQL is set to /var/lib/mysql/data. How do I mount my specific persistent volume path to that MySQL data directory path in Openshift? As i know in docker there is this command:

```
docker run -d -v myvol2:/var/lib/mysql/data mysql:latest
```

but is there an equivalence for this command in Openshift?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several configuration have to be done:

1. Create DeploymentConfig
2. Create PersistenceVolume (see [persistence volume](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/dev_guide/persistent_volumes.html#persistent-volumes-volumes-and-claim-prebinding))
3. Create PersistenceVolumeClaim
4. Add volume and mount point to DeploymentConfig (see [adding volumes](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/dev_guide/volumes.html#adding-volumes))

Creating new PersistenceVolumeClaim and adding mount point to DeploymentConfig can be done by one command:

```
oc set volume dc mysql --add --name=mysql-volume -t pvc --claim-name=mysql-pvc --claim-size=1Gi --claim-mode='ReadWriteMany' --mount-path=/var/lib/mysql/data
```

Persistence volume should be add through *oc apply*, e.g. NFS PV:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: pv0001
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteMany
  nfs:
    path: /tmp
    server: 172.17.0.2
```